# Determining which variables are used globally

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I'm trying to refactor some lengthy shell scripts and I'd like to eliminate any variables that are declared within functions, but used globally. Is there a way to quickly find these variables?

Alternatively, is there a way to quickly find out which variables are empty at use? That way I can typeset all variables within functions and quickly see a list of all those globally used variables (with some false positives, but I can weed through those).

Thanks.

Comment: For ksh, take a look at the `-R` command-line option `ksh -R outfile script`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find `set -u` helpful.  If a variable is unset when used, the shell will error out.  This will not help you find variables that are the empty string when used, but will find variables that are unset.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I've tried using ksh -R to run through a script, but it doesn't seem to observe set -u like regular runtime does. Do you know of a way to hit the errors set -u imposes without actually executing the script? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any real shortcuts here, but there are certainly some steps you can take to explore your script more systematically.

1. Find exported variables with `export -p`.
2. Grep for the `declare` keyword in your script.
3. Loop through `declare -F` and grep for declare statements or variable assignment.
4. Parse the output of `set` to exclude variables and functions you know about, and then investigate the remainder.

None of these are comprehensive solutions, I'm afraid. But to get you started:

```
# Find declare statements in functions.
for func in $( declare -F | awk '{print $NF}' ); do
    type "$func" | fgrep declare
done
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Knowing that there isn't a shortcut helps too, I just didn't want to spend all the time in the preparation without at least checking for a pre-existing tool. Thanks for your help, I'll leave the question open a bit longer to see if someone happens to know of a tool.

Comment: Note that `declare` is used by bash, but `typeset` by ksh (also supported by bash).  In addition, ksh93 does not localize variables if you use the old Bourne shell syntax for functions `func_name() {...}`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the bit about ksh function syntax. I was wondering why typeset wasn't making variables local.